# ifelse & for loop in R- help needed for a simple example

Tags: r

I am very new to R, just playing with it. I wrote some code to calculate the number of possible Heron triangles with two sides given. As many of us know, a Heron triangle has all its sides as integers as well as the area. In the code given below, a & b are integers.

```
heron <- function(a,b)
{
  d = 0
  for(c in abs(a-b)+1:a+b-1)
  {
    area <- ((1/4)*sqrt((a^2+b^2+c^2)^2-(a^4+b^4+c^4)))
    d <- ifelse(area == floor(area), d+1, d)
  }

  return(d)
}
```

The code is returning wrong values. For example, `heron(5,5)=2` but when I plug in `a=5`, `b=5`, the code it gives the answer as `0`. Looking at the code, it's obvious that there is some problem with the for loop and the ifelse part; but I am not able to figure it out, hence this question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `abs(a-b)+1:a+b-1` isn't what you think it is.  The sequence operator, `:`, has precedence.

Answer (score 2):

I see two mistake in your code.

First :  According this [Wiki Page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula) your formula is not correct you forgot a 2 (in the square root)

Second : In the for loop you have to add some extra bracket (in R `10 + 1:12 != 11:12`)

```
heron <- function(a,b)
{
  d = 0
  for(c in (abs(a-b)+1):(a+b-1))
  {
    area <- ((1/4) * sqrt((a^2+b^2+c^2)^2 - 2 * (a^4+b^4+c^4)))
    d <- ifelse(area == floor(area), d+1, d)
  }

  return(d)
}

heron(5, 5)
[1] 2
heron(13, 25)
[1] 0
```

A second solution without for loop

```
Heron <- function(a, b) {
C <- (abs(a-b)+1):(a+b-1)
Res <- sapply(C, function(i) 
                  ((1/4) * sqrt((a^2+b^2+i^2)^2 - 2 * (a^4+b^4+i^4))))
length(Res[Res == floor(Res)])
}
Heron(5, 5)
[1] 2
Heron(13, 25)
[1] 0
```

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. However, even with the correct version, the code produces NAs for some values, e.g. a=13, b=25. I could not understand why?

Comment: @user156934 : Add the extra bracket in your for loop....The error was also pointed out in the comments above by Csgillespie and Joshua Ulrich

Comment: Thanks a lot for your patience. I now understood the mistakes . Thanks again!!

Answer (score 1):

You're running into floating point math errors I assume.  If you walk thorough the calculation:

```
a <- 5
b <- 5
```

`c` I can glean from your `for loop` code, but its not doing what you think:

```
abs(a-b)+1:a+b-1
```

gives the numbers 5 through 9.  `abs(a-b)+ (1 through a+b) - 1`. rather than `(abs(a-b) + 1) through (a + b - 1)`

```
c <- 1:9

area <- 1/4 * sqrt((a^2 + b^2 + c^2)^2 - (a^4 + b^4 + c^4))

> area
[1]  9.185587 10.155048 11.592023 13.346348 15.309311 17.410485 19.605484 21.866070 24.173850
>
```

none of which are integers. thus, `d` stays at 0.

I've also dropped your for loop. You can use the vectorized nature of R to do this calculation instead.  It repeats `a` and `b` as many times as necessary to make an `area` vector the same length as `c`.

Then something like:

```
length(area[area==floor(area)])
```

Will give you the number of Heron triangles.  Someone else who knows the formula better will have to tell you whether or not its correct.

Comment: I would suggest that the `for` loop looks a bit ropey as well: `for(c in abs(a-b)+1:a+b-1)` I know you've dropped it in your solution, but it's worth explicitly pointing out.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I checked up the formula again and I found I had made a mistake in the formula :( sorry for not paying attention to the details. Now the code runs all right, so I request that the question be removed.

Comment: @user156934 you are free to delete your question, but the semantics of the `:` operator in R are worth repeating.

Comment: @user156934: Typically users shouldn't delete questions just because they're answered.